# Point-biserial correlation for non normally distributed data

Tags: distributions, correlation, normal-distribution

Can I use a point-biserial correlation if my data is not normally distributed and my sample size $N = 120$?

Comment: Is the question about the statistic itself or about its significance test?

Comment: the statistic itself

Comment: Yes, you may use the statistic for non-normal data.